# Передать параметр в метод

Tags: c#

Есть список

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 17, 20, 22, 4 };
```

который заполнен цифрами и у `List` есть метод `Filter` который принимает значение `var evens = a.Filter(x => x % 2 == 0);` и этот метод возвращает четные числа.

Вопрос:

1) Как сделать так, чтобы когда я передам в метод `a.Filter(x => x > 2)` он возвращал числа которые больше двух?

2) `a.Filter(x => x < 2)` - а здесь возвращал числа которые меньше двух.

```
namespace wandioConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> a = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 17, 20, 22, 4 };

            var evens = a.Filter(x => x % 2 == 0);

            for (int i = 0; i < evens.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(evens[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}



public static List<int> Filter(this List<int> even, Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
    List<int> b = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < even.Count; i++)
    {
        if (even[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            b.Add(even[i]);
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам эти методы, если в C# уже есть все необходимое для такой задачи? Ну вот например `var result = myIntList.Where(x=>x > 2);`, нужна проверка `x % 2`, да пожалуйста - `var result = myIntList.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Where(x=>x > 2);`, все, вот необходимый вам результат. Ну а если смотреть ваш код, то какой смысл в `Func<int, bool> predicate`, если вы дальше его не используете где либо?

Comment: Func<int, bool> predicate с помощью негл я принимаю лямбду

Comment: Ну и валяется она у вас там без дела, смысл тогда в ней? Принимать не значит использовать!

Comment: Вместо `if (even[i] % 2 == 0)` нужно `if (predicate(even[i]))`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо , все работает